# Branching a cached cloth simulation

Tags: animation, modifiers, cloth-simulation, instances

I figured out I could get cloth to sew itself without gravity issues by animating gravity. So, after several minutes I end up without between fifty and a hundred frames of cloth simulation that result in a clothed character. Now, the problem is I want to animate the character doing multiple things while wearing the same set of clothes. Is there a way to bake the simulation up to a certain point, then drop the whole thing into a scene for further animation? I'm sure I could script something, but I'm just wondering if it can be done by default. I don't want to apply the cloth simulation, because then I'd end up with a non-planar base mesh.

Comment: You would have to apply it...why the worry about a non-planar base mesh?

Comment: Because it seemed like it might make transformation calculations based off the original state of the mesh. Like, if you have a hoodie, it's going to deform differently than a piece of flat cloth temporarily pushed into that shape. That was my line of thought, anyway. Maybe there's something I'm not understanding there.

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate the cloth object in an animated state (there is an addon called *Corrective shape keys*) where vertices are already in a "clothy" way. You can then use this as a base for other animations. The problem is: The cloth modifier still takes some frames of jiggling before it is stead